# How to push array elements into object in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have some checkboxes whose value coming from json using ngFor. When I select those checkboxes and click submit, I need to capture the 'li' tag value and selected checkbox value in the form of array of object mentioned in output in code section. Here I am getting only 'li' tag value/text in the array but I am not getting how to push it into object along with selected checkbox value like output format.Here is the code below.

### home.component.html

```
 <div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
      <ul *ngFor="let item of nestedjson">
        <li class="parentNav">{{item.name}}</li>
        <li class="childData">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of item.value">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div><button type="submit" (click)="getit()">submit</button></div>
    </div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import Speech from 'speak-tts';
     import { RxSpeechRecognitionService, resultList, } from '@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

      providers: [ RxSpeechRecognitionService ]
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 
        data:any;
        nestedjson:any;
        message = '';
        test:any;
     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,public service: RxSpeechRecognitionService) {
         }

      ngOnInit() {
         this.nestedjson = [
        { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
        { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
        { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
      ];
    } 

    getit(){
        const data = this.nestedjson;
        let duplicatePushArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
      if(duplicatePushArray.indexOf(data[i].name) === -1) {
        duplicatePushArray.push(data[i].name);
      } else {
        console.log(`${data[i]} is already pushed into array`);
      }
    }    
    console.log('Final Array: ', duplicatePushArray)
   /*output: [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}]*/
    }

    }
```

Comment: is that ouput after checking all checkboxes ?? please share some scenarios and expected output

Comment: Output format is there already in the 'home.component.ts'  commented code. I need to get output once you select the checkboxes and click submit only

Comment: output- [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}]

Comment: @UIAPIDEVELOPER, if only child11 is selected, do you expect both values - from parent 1 - {"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"] or just only child11 - {"name":"parent1","value":["child11"]

Comment: {"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]}

Comment: Sorry I am expecting {"name":"parent1","value":["child11"]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything happening when the checkbox is selected. I would recommending adding an onChange binding so that you can save all of your checked children to an array that you can reference when you click submit.

home.component.html

```html
  <li *ngFor="let child of item.value">{{child}}
    <span class="pull-right">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="addtoChecked(child)">
    </span>
  </li>
```

home.component.ts

```js
private checkedChildren = <string[]>[];
public addToChecked(child: string): void {
  if(this.checkedChildren.indexOf(child) > -1){ // you can also pass in the $event from the html to this method to determine if it was checked or not
    this.checkedChildren = this.checkedChildren.filter(c => c !== child);
  } else {
    this.checkedChildren.push(child);
  }
}

getit(): void {
  const output = <{name: string, value: string[]}[]>[];
  this.checkedChildren.forEach((child) => {
    const jsonData = this.nestedjson.find(j => j.value.indexOf(child) > -1);
    if(!jsonData) {
      // something went wrong
      return;
    }

    const existingDataIndex = output.findIndex(o => o.name == jsonData.name);
    if(existingDataIndex === -1){
      output.push({ name: jsonData.name, value: [child]});
    } else {
      output[existingDataIndex].value.push(child);
    }
  });
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: I am getting only checked value after selecting checkbox into array format, but how to combine with 'li' tag  value and put it with array of object like  output- [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}]

Comment: updated answer. is that more of what you're looking for? If the child was selected, the parent object will be added to the output

Comment: updated again based on comments to question. Only the selected children will get returned with the parent objects

Comment: Thanks one issue is there suppose if I select only 'child1' its showing child1,child2 both like {"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]} , it should show only selected child

Comment: After using updated answer getting error on this line output.push({ name: jsonData.name, value[child]});  "No value exists in scope  for shorthand property value either declare one or provide initialiser"

Comment: output[existingDataIndex].value.push(child);  getting error in this line Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: try again. The if-statement on the index was not setup correctly

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce and checked flags for checkboxes

1. Add checked array to original Array to keep track of checked boxes

   this.nestedjson.forEach(v => v.checked = Array(v.value.length).fill(false));
2. Updated array of checked values based on checked checkboxes
3. Using reduce updated Final array by filtering out only checked boxes

`let duplicatePushArray = this.nestedjson.reduce((acc, v) => {
              let temp = {name: v.name, value: []};
              v.checked.forEach((val, i) => {
                if(val){
                    temp.value.push(v.value[i]);
                }
              })
              if(temp.value.length > 0){
                    acc.push(temp)
              }
              return acc
            }, []);`

Updated app.component.html and app.component.ts files below for reference

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
      <ul *ngFor="let item of nestedjson">
        <li class="parentNav">{{item.name}}</li>
        <li class="childData">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of item.value; let i = index">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" (change)="item.checked[i] = !item.checked[i]"></span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div><button type="submit" (click)="getit()">submit</button></div>
    </div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
      })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
        data:any;
        nestedjson:any;
        message = '';
        test:any;
     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
         }

      ngOnInit() {
         this.nestedjson = [
        { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
        { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
        { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
      ];

      this.nestedjson.forEach(v => v.checked = Array(v.value.length).fill(false));
    } 

    getit(){
        const data = this.nestedjson;
        let duplicatePushArray = this.nestedjson.reduce((acc, v) => {
          let temp = {name: v.name, value: []};
          v.checked.forEach((val, i) => {
            if(val){
                temp.value.push(v.value[i]);
            }
          })
          if(temp.value.length > 0){
                acc.push(temp)
          }
          return acc
        }, []);

    console.log('Final Array: ', duplicatePushArray)
   /*output: [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}]*/
    }
    }
```

Sample working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9fmyz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I implemented in my project its working fine but  in case of radio box if I check and uncheck it and check again other radio box(in case of parent1), and click submit button , Its showing into true for both in the  checked value console.log(data) ,It not working like checkbox. I mean checked status is not coming properly, here is the modificaion   <li *ngFor="let child of item.value; let i = index">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input name="{{item.name}}" value="{{child}}" type="radio" (change)="item.checked[i] = !item.checked[i]"></span></li>

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER, so it is working fine for checkboxes and failing with radio button?

Comment: Can you please help me on it,Here my main concern to capture the checked values on submit, not on  change or on select,Also I am getting empty array when my checkboxes are pre selected